# Linq and ASP.NET MVC: Order data from latest to previous

Tags: c#, linq, model-view-controller

```
 internal static IQueryable<TimeReviewDataModel> GetGridDetails(DiscoLlamaEntities context, string actor)   
    {

        return (from t in context.TimeCaptures
                join jc in context.JobCards on t.JobCardID equals jc.ID into jcSub
                from jc in jcSub.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join cu in context.Companies on jc.CustomerID equals cu.ID into cuSub
                from tg in cuSub.DefaultIfEmpty()
                where (t.CreatedBy == actor)
                orderby t.Date descending
                select new TimeReviewDataModel
                {
                    ID = t.ID,
                    CustomerName = tg.Name,
                    Date = t.Date,
                    StartTime = t.StartTime,
                    EndTime = t.EndTime,
                    Description = t.Description,
                    Category = t.Category,
                    JobCardID = t.JobCardID,
                    VsoTask = t.VsoTaskID,
                    IsBillable = (bool)t.Billable
                })
                .OrderBy(e=>e.Date);
    }
```

Hi, I'm trying to order my data in a grid. At the top I want the data that was entered today as the grid goes down I want the previously added entries. Currently it mixes the entries. I want to order using the Date property.

I'm using Linq and EntityFramework.

My Grid:

[image]

Comment: Please, Post the code is StackOverflow so people can read it more easily

Comment: remove the second OrderBy? Use TOList() to execute the code. It should be ordered . You can use DEBUGGER to preview. Maybe there is other code when filling in the grid, JS on view?

Comment: No I have no JS on view

@Jay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
return (from t in context.TimeCaptures
            join jc in context.JobCards on t.JobCardID equals jc.ID into jcSub
            from jc in jcSub.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join cu in context.Companies on jc.CustomerID equals cu.ID into cuSub
            from tg in cuSub.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where (t.CreatedBy == actor)
            //orderby t.Date descending
            select new TimeReviewDataModel
            {
                ID = t.ID,
                CustomerName = tg.Name,
                Date = t.Date,
                StartTime = t.StartTime,
                EndTime = t.EndTime,
                Description = t.Description,
                Category = t.Category,
                JobCardID = t.JobCardID,
                VsoTask = t.VsoTaskID,
                IsBillable = (bool)t.Billable
            })
            .OrderByDescending(e=>e.Date).ThenByDescending(e=>eStartTime);
```

So, here you are ordering your final dataset, not an intermediate one.